# choosing child entity based on a condintion in Linq To Entities

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have an Article and Comments entities which are related together in a one-to-many relationship. But I cant write a Linq to take only approved comments for an article. I mean if it shows an article, it only take those comments which their Approved property is set to true:

```
 public partial class Article
    {
        //
        public int ArticleID { get; set; }

         public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; } 
    }

     public partial class Comment
     {

        public int CommentID { get; set; }


        public int ArticleID { get; set; }

         public bool Approved { get; set; }

        public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
     }
```

And this the query I use to get an article item :

```
Article _article = context.Articles.
                FirstOrDefault(x => x.ArticleID == id && x.Approved == true);
```

Comment: Have you tried `context.Articles.Where(x => x.Approved)`?

Comment: It just returns Approved articles without considering whether associated comments are approved or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EF 4,1 you can do it like this

```
Article _article = context.Articles.
                FirstOrDefault(x => x.ArticleID == id && x.Approved == true);

context.Entry(_article)
        .Collection(a => a.Comments)
        .Query()
        .Where(c => c.Approved == true)
        .Load();
```

Refer [loading related entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) article for more information

Comment: What if I use Unit Of Work and dont have direct access to context ?

Comment: @persian `Context` is the "unit of work". you have a problem with your design.

Comment: I used the pattern which is described here : http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @persian it is just a sample that works on **simple situations**. You need to think and customize it to work in your situation or come up with your own.

Comment: is there any sophisticated one out there, I am a new bie

Comment: @persian since `Context` is the "unit of work" and `DbSet` is the Repository you can go ahead without creating more abstractions on top of them